# Proxy with mobile IPs

Tags: vpn, proxy, ip, mobile-devices

How can websites, like [BrightData](https://brightdata.com/), [rsocks.net](https://rsocks.net/mobile-proxy), and others, offer a proxy product that is using a mobile IP address?

To my understanding, mobile operators block all incoming communications in their NAT. So how do the clients of the proxy reach those proxy servers?

All I can think of is that maybe they initiate the communication from the mobile device itself, and get the requests of the proxy-client as the response of that communication

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (there are other approaches)

A service on the mobile device connects out to the proxy controller, maintaining a constantly open connection.

The proxy controller then routes requests down this already open connection and the service sends the responses back.

(There are also cellular providers that supply plans with fully routed addresses.)